# Conditional Delete for React-Admin List View

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I need to be able to delete a user if a flag in the user's data is true and if it is false, don't delete it and show a notification. I am fairly new to RA and don't have a lot of React experience but was able to make a custom Delete button that can determine whether the item selected is "deleteable" but I didn't know how to gracefully prevent the delete from happening and show a notification indicating why this user wasn't deleted.

In my latest attempt, I created a custom Delete button where I use the user's data to determine if it is ok to delete the use, then I use that flag to pass it into the DeleteButton's disable prop, but that doesn't seem to prevent it from deleting the user.

Here is an example of what I described above:

```
return <DeleteButton {...props} record={data} disabled={canDelete}/>
```

I am using react-admin 3.11.2

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't prevent the deletion? You can still click the disabled button?

Comment: @KiaKaha If the flag I am using is true, then allow the user to be deleted via the Delete button. Otherwise prevent and deletion from happening and show a snackbar message that says something like "User can't be deleted because ..."

Answer (score 2):

If what you are struggling with is how to handle the DeleteButton's onClick event by yourself and depending on the flag, then I would suggest the following solution:

1. Create a custom button - you can inherit react-admin's styling by importing `import { Button } from 'react-admin'`
2. Handle the `onClick` event according to the flag by 
   2.1 conditionally showing a custom `Dialog` with your message if the value is false

   2.2 calling the delete function by yourself using the `useDelete` hook. More info on the hook [here](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usedelete).

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal solution but I used this approach.  I made a custom DeleteButton that will show a delete icon only if the flag is true, otherwise there is no icon thus not allowing the delete to happen.

```
const MyDeleteButton = props => {
const { record } = props;

    if (!record.isDeletable) {
        // Note, no label, just shows an icon
        return <DeleteButton {...props} label=''/>
    } else {
        return null
}
```